# Magento 2.4.0 upgrade from Magento 2.3.5 not updating

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, backend, magento2.2.4, magento-upgrade

when i upgrade to 2.4.0 from admin area. i get all green check mark, it goes through the next step, I skip the backup process. next step it goes through normal process after couple minutes into it, it shows success! but the magento version is still 2.3.5. not updating. any idea ?

Comment: its good to upgrade magetno version using cli just change the your composer version in composer.json file and run composer update command its much more easy  and yeah dont forget to take a your db backup

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method for upgrading Magento core is to use the command line interface.

You can find a step by step guide to upgrading to Magento 2.4.0 from the command line here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html